# Condition to use a custom normalizer on symfony

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I don't know if it is a stupid question but I've looked around for it and wasn't able to find it:

Is there a way that I can use a custom normalizer based on a condition, like a path for example?

Here's the example of the symfony docs on how to create a custom normalizer:

```
/ src/Serializer/TopicNormalizer.php
namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Topic;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class TopicNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function normalize($topic, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($topic, $format, $context);

        // Here, add, edit, or delete some data:
        $data['href']['self'] = $this->router->generate('topic_show', [
            'id' => $topic->getId(),
        ], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $data instanceof Topic;
    }
}
```

As I, understand the `supportsNormalization` function is like a condition that if the entity is an instance of Topic (on this example) the entity will be serialized with that normalizer. If that's correct, how can I add or change that condition to only use the custom normalizer when used by a certain path, for example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive but, you should be able to pass a value in `$context` array to check against. Just avoid using the keys defined as constants in [`Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer`](https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/5.x/Normalizer/AbstractNormalizer.php) and [`Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractObjectNormalizer`](https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/5.x/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php)

Comment: alternatively, op could use DI to access the Request(Stack) if they meant "the request's route".